# Removing the body content of emails when I compose a reply

Tags: yahoo-mail

Every time I want to reply to an email, the main text in the body appears preloaded in the composition window.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot disable this feature of replying in Yahoo! Mail.

Best you can do is highlight all of the text and delete it.

Comment: CTRL-A, Del. Two (or three, depending on how you're counting) keystrokes.